# Setting up port forwarding on secondary router with restricted config access to primary router

Tags: router, dns, port-forwarding, wireless-bridge

I can connect to Router 1 over wifi which is connected to the internet.

I do not have access to Router 1's config settings to change any DNS, port forwarding, etc.

What I was hoping to do is connect a Router 2 to Router 1 (over Wifi or lan) and change the DNS and port forwarding on Router 2. All PC's and devices that connect to Router 2 will follow the DNS and forwarding rules of Router 2 while utilizing Router 1 for its internet connection

I have a Dlink DIR-615 as secondary router.

Is this possible?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure... for traffic going outside; you'll  be doing double NAT but that is not necessarily a problem. However if router 1 is not forwarding external ports towards router 2, how do you expect to have any use of port forwarding on router 2 (besides from inside to outside, but that's probably not what you want)?

Comment: From the inside out is indeed what I want yes.  There is some outgoing traffic that will connect to Router 2 that I want to send another way.  My problem is connecting to Router 1 with router 2 and then have it as a seperate network (loosely speaking) than that from Router 1

Comment: This is exactly my setup at home.  well, I can access router 1, but i have my own private LAN separate from the house's network connection.  If router 1 doesn't have ports open, though, then incoming traffic (for instance if you have a server behind router 2) won't connect